# change pivot source using vba won't work

Tags: vba, excel, datasource, pivot-table

I have been puzzling to have vba change the datasource for multiple pivots.
I have been reading many suggestions and none of them have helped me so far. I do not understand what I am doing wrong so I ultimately ask my question here.

Here is what I try to achieve:
I have multiple files with pivots that have to be changed because columns have been inserted and my pivot data source has changed. I want to change this to the right range. I created this code:

```
Sub change_pivotsource()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pts As PivotTables
Dim pt_source As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

workbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
sheetname = Left(workbookname, Len(workbookname) - 5)
pt_source = "'" & sheetname & "'!$A:$T"


For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    For Each PivotTable In ws.PivotTables
      pt.SourceData = pt_source
    Next PivotTable
Next ws


End Sub
```

I am using the workbook name to have the string which is the final datasource location.

How can I have the pt_source as my pivotsource for each pivot in my workbook?
Many times I get an "object or block variable with is not set" error

edit 1:

this code give me an error 7 during execution: insufficient memory:
and then it highlights the "pt_source ="-row.

```
Sub change_pivotsource()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim sheetname As String
Dim pt_source As String
Dim workbookname As String

workbookname = ThisWorkbook.Name
sheetname = Left(workbookname, Len(workbookname) - 5)
pt_source = Sheets(sheetname).Range("$A:$T")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.ChangePivotCache _
        wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
              SourceData:=pt_source)

      Next pt
Next ws
'workbook.save
End sub
```

this code solved my question:

```
Sub UpdatePivotCaches()
' Updates each pivot cache in the current workbook.
Dim pt As PivotTable        ' Used to loop over each pivot table.
Dim ws As Worksheet         ' Used to loop over each work sheet.
Dim sheetname As String
Dim pt_source As String
Dim workbookname As String

workbookname = ThisWorkbook.Name
sheetname = Left(workbookname, Len(workbookname) - 5)


    ' Loop over each sheet.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        ' Loop over each pivot table on the sheet.
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

            ' Update the pivot cache.
            pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'" & sheetname & "'!$A:$T", xlPivotTableVersion14)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Key to the solution might have been the version parameter (see the comments below this question).
Thanks to destination-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot tables get their data from a [pivot cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.changepivotcache.aspx).  It is this object we need to change.  This procedure replaces the cache connected to each pivot table within the current workbook.

```
Sub UpdatePivotCaches()
' Updates each pivot cache in the current workbook.
Dim pt As PivotTable        ' Used to loop over each pivot table.
Dim ws As Worksheet         ' Used to loop over each work sheet.


    ' Loop over each sheet.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        ' Loop over each pivot table on the sheet.
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

            ' Update the pivot cache.
            pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'Sheet1'!C8:D12", xlPivotTableVersion14)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I've hardcoded the new data source (`...'Sheet1'!C8:D12...`) but you could improve this procedure by [parameterising](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx) the range address.

If you ever get stuck with VBA try the [macro recorder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838320.aspx).  This translates your manual actions into VBA.  It's a very handy tool.

Comment: thanks. I tried the macro recorder but this did not return anything for changing my pivot source. I have multiple pivots which all use the same pivot cache. Can I simple change the code to "for each pivottable in worksheet.pivottables?

Comment: My code simply keeps asking for a with argument. None of the website I have read today with solutions have/use a with argument. I do not understand why vba keeps asking me for a with argument. I only want to change all pivot data sources to this range: **'Rustgevers - Values'!$A:$T**. But that seems kinda hard to achieve.

Comment: My answer is a little brief.  I'll update with more detial.

Comment: Thank you. I still do not see what I did wrong, but I used the updated code you have posted, changed it to the datasource I want and the routine works perfect.

Comment: Like you I couldn't get `pt.SourceData = *New Source*` to work.  I suspect this is a read only property (I must be honest; I didn't check the documentation).  I also had trouble with `PivotCaches.Create` until I included the version parameter *xlPivotTableVersion14*.